# WP_Query with different postmeta filter for each categories

Tags: wp-query, filters, meta-query

Let's say I have categories (cat1, cat2) and I have postmeta keys (date1, date2, status).

How do I view all posts in all categories with these filters:

- For cat1, I want to apply `WHERE date2 <= $today`.
- For cat2, I want to apply `WHERE status=1`.

How do I apply the `$args` for `WP_Query`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that with a single query. WP_Query is very good at [taxonomy queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) nowadays, even doing things like nested comparisons, and [custom field queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). In your case, you're trying to limit the posts returned by a meta query when another condition is true. If you go and grab only the IDs from the first two queries, you can run a third query that's very cheap to return the entire result with perfect formatting for the loop.

First, run the first meta & tax query.

```
<?php 
$today = date();
$args1 = array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'cat1',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'date2',
            'value'   => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
```

Next, run the second meta & tax query.

```
$args2 = array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'cat2',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'value'   => 1,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
```

Finally, combine the two results and run a third query for just the resulting post's IDs.

```
$all_IDs = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );

$final_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $all_IDs ) );
```

h/t [Bora Yalcin's answer for the query combination](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s)