# Combine WP_Query with array of custom data to single loop without breaking the pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, sort

Content of my loop should not be just posts. Other sources of data should be seamlessly included to it - such as newly updated terms of custom taxonomies, tweets pulled by an API or new Instagram photos.

I would like to merge those sources to a single feed as seamlessly as possible, so it would be possible to:

- Manipulate the order of "posts" by some criteria (such as object property "date_created")
- Use the pagination, that would be manipulated by the actual count of objects in the "merged loop".

Does that make sense? Here is my simplifed code, which tried to use technique described here: [Can i merge 2 new WP_Query($variable) 's?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s)

```
// Get other data
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

$mista = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'custom_tax',
    'number' => 0
));

$tweets = cibulka_tweet_getter();

// Merge data with post query
// adapted from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s    
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type' => array('post', 'cpt1', 'cpt2')
));
$wp_query->posts = $wp_posts->posts + $mista + $tweets;
$wp_query->post_count = $wp_query->post_count + count($mista) + count($tweets);

// ...
// assign each object in `$wp_query->posts` with "date_created" property, either pulled from meta (`get_post_meta`), API result or something else
// ...

// Sort data
// - note: each "query object" (post, term or tweet) has "sort_date" property assigned by me already
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

usort($wp_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
    return $b->date_created - $a->date_created;
});

// Loop through data    
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) { $wp_query->the_post();

    global $post;
    if (is_a($post, 'WP_Post')) {
        // is post, do standard post stuff such as `echo the_title()`
    }
    elseif (is_a($post, 'WP_Term')) {
        // is term, show taxonomy information
    }
    else {
        // is something else, such as result of Twitter API, work with that
    }

}
```

This way, objects are sorted correctly (by custom `sort_date` property), but pagination does not seem to be working.

I will try want to manipulate main `$wp_query` on archive pages by `pre_get_posts` action to include some non-post objects as well. For example, parent taxonomy page loop should include seemlessly merged "cards" of newly updated child terms.

That makes "finding the right way" even more important.

Could you point me somewhere please? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a hook into a query with `pre_get_posts` ?

Comment: Not yet, right now I'm trying to make it work via simple `wp_query` on the front page. If it will work, I will move on to `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: how are you going to run the loop on non-post objects? what will happen when any API functions try to use that data, like post ID?

Comment: You mean what happens in section "loop through data"? Seem update of my code, but honestly nothing special.