# WP Query: How to get posts from a specific author OR posts with a specific meta value

Tags: wp-query

i have in all of my posts an additional custom field (acf user field) in case the post has a co-author.

All users have their own author-page where all their posts are displayed. No problem so far.

But what i now want is a query where i get all posts where the author is the actual author and all posts where he/she is just the co-author in the custom field.

My code is pretty simple so far, but did not actually work. I guess the 'relation' parameter is only for comparing meta query-subarrays.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
   'posts_per_page'         => 20,
   'relation'               => 'OR',
       array(
           'author'                 => $author_ID,
            ),
       array(
           'meta_key'                => 'authorfeld',
           'meta_value'              => $showme[ID], // This is the authors id from the custom field
            )
    );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some hints here: [Can i merge 2 new WP_Query($variable) 's?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s)

So i created two separate queries and merged them into a new array:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts ); 

foreach($wp_query->posts as $post) :
setup_postdata( $post );
```

And then the usual stuff.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Real quick, are you sure you spelled the name of the meta_key correctly? It says "authorfeld" in your example, but maybe it's supposed to be "authorfield"? Also `$showme[ID]` would need to be `$showme['ID']` unless `ID` is a defined variable.

In any case, your $args array is not quite correct. Try these examples:

```
// Get the posts from this author, but not this coauthor.
$author_not_coauthor = array(
   'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
   'posts_per_page'         => 20,
   'author'                 => $author_ID,
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'authorfeld',
            'value' => $showme['ID'],
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
   ),
);

// Get the posts from this coauthor, but not this author.
$coauthor_not_author = array(
   'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
   'posts_per_page'         => 20,
   'author__not_in'         => array( $author_ID ),
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'authorfeld',
            'value' => $showme['ID'],
        ),
   ),
);
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but i think you missunderstood me. I want the query to get all the posts where the author is the mainauthor AND all the posts where he is the co-author (defined by the meta_query). Your examples give me just one of it and when i combine the query the query it gives me only the posts where he would be both.

Comment: In that case you ought to be able to use the first example, but comment out the "compare" parameter in the meta query.

Comment: Nope, doesnt work. Unfortunately. I guess i have to go with two separate queries.