# Get posts by similar names and categories

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, search

I want to write a query for my search page to show posts by two inputs. In my search form, i have to inputs, one is for category and the other is regular search term.

I want to show the posts that have the category keyword and search term. This is the code i have wrote so far :

```
$_place = $_GET['s'] != '' ? $_GET['s'] : '';
$_name = $_GET['n'] != '' ? $_GET['n'] : '';
$meta_query_args = array(
    'key'     => 'keywords',
    'value'   => $_name,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
); 

$tax_query = array(
    'taxonomy'                      =>          'category', 
    'field'                         =>          'slug', 
    'terms'                         =>          $_place, 
    'operator'                      =>          'LIKE'
); 
$adSearchQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'                     =>          'post',
        's'                             =>          $_name, 
        'meta_query'                    =>          $meta_query_args, 
        'tax_query'                     =>          $tax_query
    )   
);
```

`$_place` is the category. This code does not show any related result, in fact, most of the times it does not show anything.

So my main question is i want to show posts by similar terms (`$_name`) and similar categories (`$_place`).

By similar, i mean when i search the `abc` keyword, it shows the `abcde` or `h abc d` .

Comment: Define 'similar'.

Comment: What is the `$meta_query_args` for? The current code searches for posts that have `$_name` in a custom field named `keywords`, in addition to matching the `$_name` search term (`'s'` argument) and being in the `$_place` category (`'tax_query'` arg).

Comment: @jacob-peattie I edited the question with 'similar' definition.

Comment: @iceable Yes you are right, `$meta_query_args` is extra but it still look for the posts with categories exactly the same as `$_place`.

Comment: What you have is an "AND" query: 'keywords' LIKE $name AND search_term LIKE $name AND 'category' LIKE $place. What you want is a combination "AND" and "OR" query: ('keywords' LIKE $name OR search_term LIKE $name) AND 'category' LIKE $place. See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123193/129019