# WP_Query showing all posts, except from category X, unless it's also in Y

Tags: wp-query, categories

I'm trying to show posts from categories A, B, C, D...and Y, except X, unless posts in X are also in Y, then show them with the rest.

I can hide category X on it's own pretty simply:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => '-X',
);
```

I've tried to [combine two loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123193/10110), one getting all posts excluding X, the other getting posts that are in both X and Y, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$EverythingButXLoop_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => '-X',
);
$EverythingButXLoop = new WP_Query( $EverythingButXLoop_args );

$OnlyXwithYLoop_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'categoryX+categoryY',
);
$OnlyXwithYLoop = new WP_Query( $OnlyXwithYLoop_args );

$mainLoop_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$mainLoop = new WP_Query( $mainLoop_args );
$mainLoop->posts = array_merge( $EverythingButXLoop->posts, $OnlyXwithYLoop->posts );

//populate post_count count for the loop to work correctly
$mainLoop->post_count = $EverythingButXLoop->post_count + $OnlyXwithYLoop->post_count;
```

I've also thought about getting all category ID's in a var(instead of listing every one of my many other categories) and using it with a category parameter to exclude posts in X...somehow, ie. `'cat' => $categoryIDs, 'category__not_in' => 'X'` but I think I'm still just faced with the original problem: **excluding X, except when in X and Y**

Any idea what's not working with the combining technique above, or how I can achieve this another (better) way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp_query`, you should use `NOT IN` which I don't see. In your arguments for `WP_Query()`, you should use `category__not_in` instead of `cat`. So, change your code to:

**Excluding Single Category**

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'category__not_in' => 'X', // string
);
```

If you wish to exclude multiple categories then assign the category ID's comma separated in an array, not as a string. Check the below code

**Excluding Multiple Categories and Displaying Posts That are from X and Y**

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'category__in' => array(X,Y), // Array
  'post__not_in' => array(X),
);
```

Below is the full Query:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'category__in' => array(X,Y), // Array
  'post__not_in' => array(X),
);

$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  while( $your_query->have_posts() ):
  $your_query->the_post();
  the_title();
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Note: Use ID not the category slug or name**

Comment: According to the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), `cat => '-285'` works fine to exclude categories, and I can confirm it does because I've tested it. This isn't the problem though if you read through my entire post. I need to not only exclude category X, but also allow it if it is paired with category Y.

Comment: For that, you don't need to combine them and merge. I have updated the code. That pulls the categories from combined from both categories.

Comment: I wound grab all the posts and filter later with a foreach unsetting the ones belonging ONLY to cat X. I dont't see a straight solution with just a wp_query

Comment: I think the `'category__in' => array(X,Y), 'post__not_in' => array(X),` still will not show what I need. I believe that's going to only get posts in X and Y, and then exclude posts in X, leaving us with only posts in Y. Right? Maybe I should've made it more clear(I edited my OP) that I need **all posts** from every other category—so posts from categories A, B, C, D...and Y, except X, unless posts in X are also in Y. Let me know if that doesn't make sense or is unclear. I realize it's a bit of an odd query.